# Search for multiple conditions on same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL, how to select all rows that satisfy multiple AND conditions (not OR) of the *same* column?

Such as: "select all users who speak these 3 languages (language_id == 1 AND language_id == 2 AND language_id ==3)" where language_id is a column

```
id | user_id | language_id 
--------------------------
1  |    1    |     1     
2  |    2    |     1     
3  |    2    |     2     
4  |    3    |     1     
5  |    4    |     1   << which users speak this language )
6  |    4    |     2   << AND speak this language         ) => expected result: user_id == 4
7  |    4    |     3   << AND speak this language         ) 
8  |    5    |     1     
9  |    6    |     1    
10 |    7    |     1
```

Comment: what type is `language_id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select all users having the wanted languages, count the languages and then restrict the users to have the language count equal to the count of the wanted languages.

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM (SELECT used_id,COUNT(*)
          FROM [table_name]
         WHERE language_id IN (1,2,3)
         GROUP BY user_id
        HAVING COUNT(*)=3
       ) i;
```

Comment: I would say that this solution does not return the desired result. Imagine an additional record with user_id=2 and language_id=1. Your query would return the user_id 2 as the count would be 3, but this would not be the desired result...

Comment: @Jortx I would assume that this is not a valid case anyway. It could be enforced with an unique index containing user_id, language_id.

Comment: I agree with @dgw and thank you for the amazingly compact and efficient solution, which indeed works as long as rows have unique [user_id, language_id] pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You have some ways to do that.

One simple way would be to create a view returning the user_id with the count for each language, for example:

```
CREATE VIEW myView
AS
SELECT DISTINCT T0.user_id
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [myTable] WHERE user_id=T0.user_id AND language_id=1) AS L1
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [myTable] WHERE user_id=T0.user_id AND language_id=2) AS L2
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [myTable] WHERE user_id=T0.user_id AND language_id=3) AS L3
FROM [myTable] AS T0
GO
```

You should get a result like this:

[image]

Then, you only need to query this view, getting just the user_id where L1>0 AND L2>0 AND L3>0...

```
SELECT * FROM myView WHERE L1>0 AND L2>0 AND L3>0
```

Regards,

Comment: That view is not very efficient, because it has to query the table one time for each wanted language. For large tables this will be quite slow. And if one wants to search for three other languages or even four languages the view has to be created again.

Comment: Of course not very efficient, but it works. I test my answers. Waiting for your more efficient way ;-)